# Fill attribute-table on feature-creation based on intersection with other layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, digitizing

I am digitising line-features based on WGS-84 point-coordinates from a PDF which cannot be copied from.

The final line layer should contain lines which each connect two points and have the following attributes:

- Name of start point - name of end point
- value in [ft]
- value in [m]
- remark (same for all features)
- date of creation

Currently I have a csv-based point layer which simply contains the name and coordinates of each point.

---

Creating the point layer is no problem, but creating the lines is a bit of a hassle. Either I manually create a `.csv` containing all existing connections between points like the following table and run `connect by lines`:

[image]

Or I digitise the lines manually but fill in the values (except for the value in [ft]) automatically.

---

Personally I would prefer option 2, since option 1 involves more manual work and the process has to be repeated regularly (and I figure I could transfer the solution to other tasks), but I can't get the expression right which should fill in the name of the line. All other values are created flawlessly (though they are not taken from another layer based on geometry).

I added the WKT of each point to the point-layer. Currently I am running the following, which returns `NULL`, despite it seems to be correct to me:

```
attribute(get_feature('point-layer','geom',geom_to_wkt(start_point($geometry))),'Waypoint')||' - '||attribute(get_feature('point-layer','geom',geom_to_wkt(end_point($geometry))),'Waypoint')
```

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try the aggregate function to get the value of `WayPoint` where the object in `point-layer` intersects the start_point (and end_point) of the digitised line.  This might work better than trying to compare the WKTs:

```
aggregate(layer:='point-layer', aggregate:='max', expression:="WayPoint",
          filter:= intersects( $geometry, start_point(geometry(@parent)))) 
||' - '||  
aggregate(layer:='point-layer', aggregate:='max', expression:="WayPoint",
          filter:= intersects( $geometry, end_point(geometry(@parent))))
```

This only works in QGIS 3, the `geometry(@parent)` function wasn't available in QGIS 2.x