# QGIS create line-layer from points, sorted by date/time

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

I have point data from telemetrie of a raptor-bird. The point-layer has `id`, `longitude`,
`lattitude` and `datetime`-fields. 
Now I want to create a line-layer which connects all the points, sorted by `datetime`.
 So for example the first line would connect the points 1 and 2, the second line the points 2 and 3 the third line the points 3 and 4 and so on.
As addtitional attribute-data each line should contain the `datetime`-value from its starting point.

[image]

I alread tried the "*points to path*" algorithm, but this gives me either a single polyline (I need seperate lines for each point-connection) or, if I try to group the lines for example by datetime, multiple single lines with the length of 0.
I also used the algorithm `explode lines` on the polyline/path, which gives me the needed single lines, but I cannot figure out how to give them the `datetime`-attribute from their starting point.
All referred QGIS-Plugins (points2one, pointConnetr etc) I found on StackExchange doesn't work on QGIS 3.x or are discontinued at all.

Comment: Once you `exploded lines` you can try to adapt [the answer to this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325464/fill-attribute-table-on-feature-creation-based-on-intersection-with-other-layer).