# Expression to fetch polygon value intersecting end of line

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, intersection, qgsexpression

I have a line layer and a polygon layer. I'm trying to create an expression to fetch a polygon attribute and add it to the line, based on in which polygon the line ends.

```
array_last(overlay_intersects('ok_ak_riks', kommunkod))
```

This isn't always working. How can I modify it? I've been thinking of if I can use `end_point($geometry)` somehow?

It is working for line 1 and 2, but not 3 (3 is one line, although the symbology is two arrows) `end_polygon` should be 2505:

[image]

Comment: Similar issue with another working possibility: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325464/fill-attribute-table-on-feature-creation-based-on-intersection-with-other-layer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `aggregate()` with an `intersects()` filter:

```
aggregate(
'ok_ak_riks',
'concatenate',
"kommunkod",
filter:=intersects($geometry,end_point(geometry(@parent))),
concatenator:=','
)
```

---

Previous / alternative answer:

```sql
array_to_string(
    array_filter( 
        array_foreach( -- 2. iterate over ALL intersecting features
            overlay_intersects('ok_ak_riks',$currentfeature), -- 1. get ALL intersecting features
            if(
                intersects(geometry(@element),end_point($geometry)), -- 3. check if the current one intersects with the lines endpoint
                attribute(@element,'kommunkod'), -- 4a. if it does, return the attribute
                '' -- 4b. otherwise return an empty string
            )
        ),
    @element <> '') -- 5. filter out the empty strings from the array
)
```

*Explanation:
you can first get all intersecting features as array by using `overlay_intersects('ok_ak_riks',$currentfeature)`, then iterate over this array by using `array_foreach()` and filter to the intersecting ones with your endpoint by testing if the current one intersects with your endpoint `if(intersects(geometry(@element),end_point($geometry))`. This will return the feature of `ok_ak_riks` intersecting with the lines end. At this point you will get an array like `['','your attribute','','']` where you never know at which position your value is. So you can use `array_filter(array,@element <> '')` to remove all empty values.*

Answer (score 4):

Use this expression with `poly` as name of the polygon layer and `number` as the attribute fieldname you want to get:

```
array_max (
    array_foreach ( 
        overlay_intersects( 'poly', $id),
        if (
            within (end_point ($geometry), geometry (get_feature_by_id('poly',@element))),
            attribute (get_feature_by_id('poly',@element), 'number'),
            ''
        )
    )
)
```

*The expression used as a dynamic label for the lines:*
[image]