# Join sub-catchment centroid using line and import attributes of it using QGIS Model builder

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, sqlite

Input Data:
I have a sub catchment polygon shapefile, which contain following details

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| TG_ID | Name of the Sub-catchment |
| Hoehe | Average height |
| Slope | Average slope |
| UTM_x_m | centroid x value |
| UTM_y_m | centroid y value |
| Km2 | Area |

The link to the input data:
[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fyi6zedletmhsgo/AACrYcpK5dLkscziN8Y8yJQea?dl=0)

[image]

**Workflow that I wish to accomplish:**

1. Create centroid point shapefile of the sub-catchment (vector-->Geometry-->centroid, which take the properties of the polygon shapefile automatically)

[image]

[image]

2. Create a line shapefile and connect the centroid of the sub-catchments - manually (How sub-catchments are connected to each other)

[image]

3. Now I am expected to create an “TG_TO” attribute in this centroid shapefile layer, how these sub-catchments are connected to each other. For example, like below

[image]

Is there any way to automate this in QGIS model builder ?

Comment: How do you create the line layer?

Comment: I create the line layer manually

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325464/fill-attribute-table-on-feature-creation-based-on-intersection-with-other-layer - this should give you an idea how to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Erik
I have already comment on this post to elaborate bit more about the use of that script, I wanted to know how that function works and in which layer (point or line)

Comment: @M Bain
Can you please help on this issue