# Concatenate points values in a field of a line

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, vector

I'd like to know how to concatenate points values (attribute data), using fields calculator of QGIS, putting this concatenation in a new field of the linear feature which connect some points of these.

For example, i'd like to get a new field called "name" in the linear layer, putting the concatenation of the field "type" of the points connected; from start point to the end point:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please check this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325464/fill-attribute-table-on-feature-creation-based-on-intersection-with-other-layer) for a direction. It's no duplicate, but a rather similar one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this in the field calculator in the lines layer

```
array_to_string(
    overlay_intersects(
        'layer',
        "type"
    ),
    ','
)
```

Replace `layer` with the layer name / id of the point layer.

Use this to return the data ordered by the position of the point in the line:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='Points layer name/id', -- set here the points layer name/id
    aggregate:='concatenate',
    expression:=to_string("type"), -- set here the field to be concatenated from points
    filter:=intersects(
        $geometry,
        geometry(@parent)
    ),
    order_by:=array_filter(
        array_foreach(
            generate_series(
                1,
                num_points(geometry(@parent))
            ),
            array(
                @element,
                point_n(
                    geometry(@parent),
                    @element
                )
            )
        ),
        intersects(
            $geometry,
            @element[1]
        )
    )[0][0],
    concatenator:=',' -- set here the concatenator
)
```

Result, red tags are the concatenated fields from points.
[image: result]

Comment: Is it possible that i get only the start point and the end point concatenated "c,e" (in the case of 3 points connected)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I'd like to have an output as the question on top (all 3 vertices concatenated from start point to the end), but i'm trying your solution (array_to_string.....) and it doesn't work. Is it possible?

Comment: It works! Thx! Is it also considered the order of the points in the concatenation (as in the image) or the "type" will be random?